# How to send request to another server with IIS ARR if a timeout occurs?

Tags: windows, iis, load-balancing, arr, web-farm

I need to setup a **Web Farm with IIS 8/10**.
I'm experienced in managing IIS on a single machine, but not in a load-balancing scenario.

I am planning to use **Application Request Routing (ARR)**.

Can I set-up ARR in IIS with a rule stating « ***Send request to Server A, then, and if no answer was received within 3 seconds, then send request to server B*** »?
Do you think that ARR would be capable of handling such a scenario ?

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion iis load balancing does not have this functionality.

by using iis load balancing you can implement the below thing:

if you have server A and server B.

the request goes to the iis and if server A is not available it will redirect the request to server B and it will serve the response.

ARR has a time-out value which is proxy time-out. by using this request will wait for the backend server to respond to the request made. if it times out connect will be closed.

You could refer to below link for more detail about iis load balancing:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-arr/http-load-balancing-using-application-request-routing